# How to write the first page for conference talk in beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer

I would to prepare a beamer presentation for a conference talk in Mathematics.

I want to display the very first page exactly like [this slide](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ekarem001/Benasquetalk.pdf).

What would be the `source code` for the beamer style of the above slide ?

I want to display in the first page the followings sequentially as in the above attachment:

(i) title of the talk

(ii) author name

(iii) author's institution

(iv) joint work with coauthor

(v) conference name

(vi) date of talk

---

I have tried the following source code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title[Your Short Title]{Your Presentation}
\author{You}
\institute{Where You're From}
\date{Date of Presentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

> What would be the correct tex.style of the source code of the slide ?

Thanks

Comment: The "correct" way to to do this would probably be to use `\setbeamertemplate`: see [the guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), but I'm lazy and would probably just stick everything else inside the date field: `\date{{\scriptsize Joint Work With Someone \\[\baselineskip] Such and Such Conference \\ Date of Presentation }}`. If it's truly cowritten you could also use the `\inst` command as described on page 92 of the guide.